# Expected Squared Error Derivation of Least Square Model (in The Elements of Statistical Learning Book)

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares, covariance, joint-distribution

I'm studying chapter 2.5 of The Elements of Statistical Learning by T.Hastie.
Here, they assume the ground truth relation between Y and X as
$$
Y=X^T\beta +\varepsilon,
$$
where $\varepsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

Subsequently, they fit the least square model to the training dataset $\tau$ and then analyze the expected squared prediction error through equations (2.27), breaking it down into bias-variance terms as follows:

[image]

Also, here they state that as $N$ increase, in the case where $E(X)=0$, $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\to N\text{Cov}(X)$ (here, $N$ is the number of data points in $\tau$).

Here, I have two questions.

The first one is that they define $\tau$ as a training dataset of size $N$ and treat it like a random variable. Then, can we regard $\tau$ as a random variable following the joint distribution for $N$ input vectors $X_1, \cdots, X_N$ and $N$ scalar labels $y_1, \cdots y_N$ as $\tau \sim P(X_1, \cdots, X_N, y_1, \cdots, y_N)$?.

My second question concerns the part where they mentioned that $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ converges to $N\text{Cov}(X)$ as $N$ increases. I agree with this statement. However, I believe that $E_{\tau}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}) = N\text{Cov}(X)$ holds true regardless of the size of $N$, due to expectation. My justification for this is as follows.

$\mathbf{X}$ is the design matrix that has the $i$-th input vector $X_i$ as a row: $$\mathbf{X} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
- & X_1 & - \\
- & X_2 & - \\
& \cdots & \\
- & X_N & -
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Also, the following holds true:
$$
\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} = X_1X_1^T+X_2X_2^T+\cdots+ X_NX_N^T.
$$
Therefore, by the definition of covariance, the following holds:
$$E_{\tau} (X_1X_1^T+\cdots+X_NX_N^T) = E_{X_1}(X_1X_1^T)+\cdots+E_{X_N}(X_NX_N^T)=N\text{Cov(X)}.$$

Hence, $E_\tau(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})=N\text{Cov}(X)$ holds true regardless of the size of $N$.

If my claim is correct, I believe the mention of  $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\to N\text{Cov}(X)$ in the book is unnecessary.
Moreover, I believe that in the first line of equation (2.28), which follows equation (2.27), there should be an equal sign ($=$) instead of an approximation sign ($\approx$)."

[image]

If there is something I am misunderstanding, I would really appreciate it if you could correct me.

Comment: I think they mean Expectation not as $N\rightarrow \infty$. the LHS goes to infinity, so it is not converging